# Database does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered corrwctly

Tags: java, sql-server, vert.x

I am building a vert.x web service using java and sql server database. I can connect successfully to my database, named mydatabase60. However when it is running the piece of code where i have USE my database right after the database connection, I have the error below. I was searching long time but can not figure this out. Much appreciate your help. I can provide my code here if needed.

> connectToDb ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Connection succeeded inIc
>   UNSUCCEEDED:  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   Database 'mydatabase60' does not exist. Make sure that the name is
>   entered correctly.    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1608)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:578)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:508)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:243)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:218)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:493)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.execute(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:67)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.JDBCQuery.execute(JDBCQuery.java:48)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.JDBCQuery.execute(JDBCQuery.java:30)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.AbstractJDBCAction.handle(AbstractJDBCAction.java:58)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.AbstractJDBCAction.lambda$execute$0(AbstractJDBCAction.java:66)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:273)
>     at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: And *does* the database `mydatabase60` exist on the server you are connecting to? The error says it does not, and I very strongly expect it doesn't. Why not just declare that database in your connection string, rather than connecting to a different database (`master`?) and then using `USE {Database Name};`?

Comment: If you want us to be able to help please read [ask] and show us some code. Right now all we can do is guess what your code might be doing.

Comment: 'mydatabase60' and 'mydatabase6O' are two different strings. Hope you checked this. What about connectivity to server from dev/port/permission related issues?